# What is the difference between TensorRT GA and RC?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt

I just wanted to download `TensorRT` but I saw there are two different versions `GA` and `RC`. What is the differences between them and what version should I choose as I use a Windows 10 machine with Geforce GTX 960M graphic card?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GA is a production release, it stands for "**G**eneral **A**vailability".   It is the version most people should be using, for most activities.  It has gone through a full test cycle.

RC is a "**R**elease **C**andidate". It is a preproduction version, an early release version. In general, the recommendation would be to use a GA version, unless you have a specific reason to use a RC version (e.g. to evaluate a new feature).  RC might be used to evaluate a specific new capability before it is available in a GA release, or it might be used to evaluate compatibility of a current code or application with future plans.

Recommondation based on your question: Use the GA version.

Note that each release is numbered, and a numbered release or release "cycle" could have (first) a RC version followed later by a GA version.